# How to get anchor point of SymbolItem

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I can't figure out how to retrieve registration point that I see in properties panel transform section in script.

[image: transform]

I use this script documentation http://ai.aenhancers.com/jsobjref/SymbolItem/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell they are just coordinates of the symbol's center. You can get them this way:

```
var symbol = app.activeDocument.selection[0];

var X =  symbol.position[0] + symbol.width/2;
var Y = -symbol.position[1] + symbol.height/2;

alert("X: " + X + "\n" + "Y: " + Y);
```

Comment: no, they are not just center, its an anchor point coordinates (pivot point)

Comment: Yep. My bad. Unfortunately you're right. It seems this is yet another feature that doesn't have a proper implementation in Illustrator's DOM. 

RegistrationPoint is matching with the center of a given symbol only in a fresh created symbols with default settings. I don't know how to get its coordinates if they were changed manually.